# How can I access default iOS sound to set it as notification sound?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

How can I access default iOS sound (Tri-tone, Chime, Glass, Horn, Bell, Electronic...) to set it as local notification sound?

I've created local notification, everything works but with default sound (which is Tri-tone). I want to use Chime or another

I only know how to use my own sound files:

```
localNotif.soundName = @"sound.wav";
```

Comment: How did you accessed "tri-tone" sound? I cannot find the correct sound id for it. thnx!

Answer (score 12):

check out [this](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices) site.

If you want to play a Default System Sound. refer a following code, but private Frameworks. you will be rejected.

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1004);
```

and check out other [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SysSound/) sample code (No private frameworks. supported a Apple).

Answer (score 3):

System sounds are not available you your app, unfortunately. From [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007916-CH3-SW8):

> Note: System-supplied alert sounds and system-supplied user-interface
>   sound effects are not available to your iOS application. For example,
>   using the kSystemSoundID_UserPreferredAlert constant as a parameter to
>   the AudioServicesPlayAlertSound function will not play anything.

**Update**

While Apple does say you can't access system sounds, I suppose they must mean that you can't access them for your own purposes, but I see that UILocalNotification.h provides:

```
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
```

"Identifies the default system sound to play when a notification alert is displayed. You assign this value to the soundName property." I am now using this in my app and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Ben, is your app certed and live in App Store?

Comment: @KennyLim Yes, but let me double-check later to make sure this code is in there. 95% sure it is.

Comment: The system note quoted above ONLY means that the constants defined accessing system sounds are not available on iOS. It does not mean that the actual sounds are not available on iOS.  MacOS has the sound settings (formerly control panel) that lets you set the alert sound etc.  That is what those constants are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

Audio services are not private.  The methods are documented in the developers reference guide and referenced in the [Multimedia Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html).

All you need to do if figure out the reference id of the sound you want to play.